# 3TB partition disappeared by Windows 7

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, gpt

I am wondering if anyone can help me with a problem...

I have a dual-boot Ubuntu and Windows 7 system.  I bought a new 3TB HDD as I needed more storage space (the HDD is not used to boot the system).  I created a GPT table and a single 3TB NTFS partition on the new HDD using GParted in Ubuntu.  I then proceeded to transfer files onto this 3TB HDD in Winodws 7.

Everything was going well until the drive capacity hit 2TB (I think).  Then I started having problems copying.  After rebooting, I found the partition has disappeared along with all the data.  GParted gave me an error message that the partition had been altered to use less than the capacity and asked me if I want to fix it.  Even after pressing "Fix" the partition is still gone.

Any one has any suggestions on how I might recover the partition and the data in either Ubuntu or Windows?

Many Thanks

Comment: Your 2TB limit sounds more like MBR (msdos)? Post this: sudo parted -l  Is this an external drive? Some caddies or some systems with older BIOS do not support large drives even if gpt.

Answer (score 0):

try to to split the capacity of the drive to small partitions like 1TB each, or 500gb, i think it will not have issues, although it is a bit strange to see this happen